# AngularJS: Unable to pass a factory's $http.get result to the controller (via $routeProvider)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, promise

I have a CRUD operation I would like to reuse, so I have a factory that gets passed to the controller via the $routeProvider/resolve.

But I see that the controller resolves before the factory's GET request comes back.
How can I set up promises so that $routeProvider doesn't pass `undefined` to the controller?

**My example:**

```
angular
  .module('app',['ngRoute'])
  .config(config)
  .controller('appController', appController)
  .factory('appFactory', appFactory);

function config($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
      templateUrl: 'template.html',
      controller: 'appController',
      resolve: {
        server_stuff: function(appFactory){
          // logging
          console.log('appFactory.serverReponse = '+ appFactory.serverResponse() );
          return appFactory.serverResponse();
        }
      }
    });
}

function appController( $scope, server_stuff ){
  $scope.content = server_stuff;
  // logging
  console.log('server_stuff = '+server_stuff);
}

function appFactory($http){
  var i = 1;
  var appFactory = {
      serverResponse: serverResponse
  };
  // logging
  console.log('Factory execution');
  return appFactory;

  function serverResponse(){
    // logging
    console.log('pre-GET ' + i);
    $http.get('/endpoint/')
      .success(function(data){
        // logging
        console.log('GET is done ' + i);
        i++
        return data;
      });
  }
}
```

**Log Ouputs:**

```
'Factory execution'
'pre-GET 1'
'appFactory.serverReponse = undefined'
'pre-GET 1'
'server_stuff = undefined'
'GET is done 1'
'GET is done 2'
```

**My changes:**

*router resolve:* I chose to pass the $http function and execute later

```
return appFactory.server; // no paren
```

*factory simplification:*

```
return $http.get('/endpoint/);
```

*controller:* utilize the injected factory as the server call that it should be…

```
function appController( $scope, server_stuff ){
  server_stuff().success( function(data){
    // do stuff with the server info
});
```

Comment: `return data;` in your `.success` does not return `data` from severResponse. you should return the promise directly instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KevinB said working with $http call in factory should look this :

**In your Factory**

```
  function serverResponse(){
    // logging
    console.log('pre-GET ' + i);
    return $http.get('/endpoint/')
      .success(function(data){
        // logging
        console.log('GET is done ' + i);
        i++
      });
  }
```

**In a controller :**

```
 MyFactory.serverResponse().success(function(data){
      //your controller handling of the data.
 });
```

**In a router resolve :**

```
resolve: {
        server_stuff: function(appFactory){
          return appFactory.serverResponse();
        }
      }
```

Your router resolve will handle by itself the success of the $http call.

Comment: Thank you both, KevinB and Okazari. 
This definitely helped me move the $http promise around to where it would work.